# How do I get an Xstream mobile phone working as a modem?

Tags: 11.10, modem, phone, internet-connection

I bought a CDMA mobile phone that can use as modem, this http://smartfren.com/xstream/ and i wanna try it on my ubuntu

plug usb , and run "lsusb"

> callmegus@Presario-CQ43-304AU:~$ lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 058f:a001 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1bbb:0106 T & A Mobile Phones 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 15d9:0a4c Trust International B.V. USB+PS/2 Optical Mouse
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0a5c:21e3 Broadcom Corp.
```

I successfully "modprobe" this device, and connect to internet, but it's disconnected somehow .. and i can recconect it.

I try "lsusb" again .. and something went wrong, here

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1bbb:1000 T & A Mobile Phones
```

I do "modprobe" again and again , but it still won't connect

Please guide me

Answer (score 1):

I do modprobe vendor=0x1bbb product=0x6000. I also install wvdial. When I run wvdialconf, the device detected as modem attached on /dev/ttyUSB3. Then I can connect to internet.